# Vertically And Horizonatally center main wrap div

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to center DIV in DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div)

Now i try

```
<html>
<head>

        <title>?????????????????</title>
        <style type="text/css">   
    body
    {

            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right:auto;
    }

    #wrap
    {
            background: black;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            height:450px;
            width:450px;
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            right:50%;
            left:50%;
            margin-top:-225px;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="wrap">
                Hello
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

?????

Comment: Have tags been placed by robot?

Comment: @Bar at least it doesn't have C++ tag anymore ...

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350/practical-solution-to-center-vertically-and-horizontally-in-html-that-works-in-ff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>?????????????????</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        #content
        {
            background: black;
            margin: -225px;
            height: 450px;
            width: 450px;
        }
        #wrap
        {
            height: 0px;
            width: 0px;

            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="content">
                Hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

`vertical-align` does not work the way most beginners expect it to work.

[Here](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html) is one tutorial explaining the situation. It sounds like you want Method 1.

Comment: I would advise you click the link and do what it tells you to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>?????????????????</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    .ui-container
    {
        background: red;
    }
    .ui-wrapper
    {
        margin: auto;
        background: black;
        height:450px;
        width:450px;
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-container">
        <div class="ui-wrapper">
                <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/09/25/absolute-horizontal-and-vertical-centering-via-css/) covers a method that has worked well for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

People may hate me for suggesting this, but place it within a `TD`, where vertical-aligning is still doable without inflicting any harm on yourself.

I've provided a working examples here: http://jsbin.com/ezolu3/edit

The markup follows:

```
<table id="vCent">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="center">

        <div id="foo">
          <p>Using tables incorrectly is wrong, without question. But sometimes there are other things that are more wrong - "wrongerer," if you will. Causing yourself unnecessary frustration trying to get an element to center itself vertically, for example, is one of those <em>wrongerer</em> things. Don't bother, just go with what works.</p>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```