# How can I center the loading div before load() with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code:

```
$("#result").html('<div class="loading">Loading results...</div>');
$("#result").load('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/GetResults.php?' + $.cookie('nw-query'));
```

It shows the loading div until the load is done. What I want to do here, I want the loading div exactly in the center of the page/document?

- That's extra but could be nice - can I also fade the document until the load is done so that the loading div stands out?

Any jquery/css suggestions are welcome.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If understand you question correctly: You need to figure out how to center the loading div both horizontally and vertically? If so, I would take a look at the answers to this question: [Practical solution to center vertically and horizontally in HTML that works in FF, IE6 and IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350/practical-solution-to-center-vertically-and-horizontally-in-html-that-works-in-ff).

Comment: +1 I agree. Put you load screen up there until you have the contents and just replace the "loading" div

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at jQueryUI?  You could use a modal dialog for this.  jQueryUi automatically centers the modal dialog and you can make the dialog disappear after it's finished loading.  There is a way to remove the title bar from the dialog:
http://www.comanswer.com/question/jquery-ui-dialog-how-to-initialize-without-a-title-bar

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but it might avoid some headaches for you later down the road (and it's pretty and you can have custom themes).

Answer (score 0):

you could put a center div around your loading...

```
$("#result").html('<div align="center" style="width:100%"><div class="loading">Loading results...</div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.loading {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background:#CCC;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-25px 0 0 -100px; /* Half of height and width */
    }
```

If you don't know width/height or it is dynamic, you can use .width() and .height() functions to get values, which should be divided by 2.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit over-kill but the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) plugin could achieve those effects (you would just not be using it for a dialog...). Check out the modal option and example. If you are using jQuery ui already, might be worth it...

Comment: I think it is pretty nice. But can you show me to how to initialize it? Do i need to replace that with html() or what?

Comment: Really simple. Just define some html as you normally would, select it and call $('div.mydialog').dialog({modal : true); on it.